# Prove that elements of the group of primitive residue classes mod n are relatively prime to n

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

My proof:
If $n$ is prime, every element other than 0 is relatively prime, and we have already shown that zero cannot be in this group as it does not have an inverse. Let $n$ be a composite number. Suppose that $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ contains elements that are not relatively prime to $n$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, there exist primes $p_1, \dots p_n$ such that $p_1 \dots p_n = n$. But $p_1, \dots p_n \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, so in order for $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ to be closed, we must have $0 \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$. Since $0$ has no inverse in $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$, this is a contradiction and we are done.

Something about this feels wrong, but I'm not really sure what.

Comment: What definition of the group of primitive residues are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to show that the invertible elements mod $n$ are exactly the numbers which are coprime to $n$.

Suppose $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, i.e $\gcd(a,n)=1$. By a standard property of the $\gcd$ there are some $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ka+ln=1$. By taking residue mod $n$ on both sides we get $ka\equiv 1$(mod $n$). So the residue class of $a$ is indeed invertible in this case.

Conversely, suppose the residue class of $a$ is invertible mod $n$. This implies there is an integer $k$ such that $ak\equiv 1$(mod $n$). This means $n|(ak-1)$, i.e there is some $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $ak-1=nc$, or equivalently $ak-nc=1$. So now if we let $d=\gcd(a,n)$ then $d|a$ and $d|n$, hence $d$ must divide $ak-nc=1$ as well. So $d=1$.